# MYSQL / opening and closing connections or keeping one open per browser user?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

If I were designing a new system, should I have each function open and close the mysql connection as and when needed OR should I form one connection and keep that as a "globally accessible variable" for that browser session?

Why is it a bad idea, if indeed it is?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information in order to answer this.

Comment: You probably should use a connection pool, but what kind of application is this, what framework/language/etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumning we're speaking about a web application here:

It's usually better to have a single connection for processing entire **request** (not session). Less overhead, less connections used from connection pool (so more clients can connect simlutaneously), easier to work with transactions etc. Only drawback I can see, is it can be a bit more difficult to code for that.